# Coffeescript local Development & Require.js Plugin Performance

Tags: javascript, performance, coffeescript, requirejs

We'd like to experiment with coffeescript and eventually convert all js code to coffee. As we are using [require.js](http://requirejs.org/) I assume the simplest approach regarding the loading part for **local development** is to use the [require.js coffeescript plugin](http://requirejs.org/docs/download.html#cs) and adjust the module loading accordingly, e.g.

```
var myModule = require('cs!myModule');
```

Does this procedure, which if my understanding is correct implies that all .coffee files are compiled on the fly, run the risk of becoming a **performance issue** quickly and therefore might slow development down significantly?

If so, what alternative do you suggest?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess whether or not this will become a performance issue depends largely on the size and structure of your application.  From my experience, compiling coffeescript doesn't take a great deal of time, but I've only ever used it with fairly small projects (5-10 files, ~50 lines each).

Since Require.js allows you to split up your code nicely into modules that will only be loaded when they're required, it should be possible to structure your app in such a way that only a few coffeescript files need loaded & compiled for each page load.

The only alternative that I have tried is to run the coffeescript compiler from the command line in watch mode.  In this mode it will watch your coffeescript files, and then compile them into javascript whenever it detects changes.  (Though as an aside I've found that this isn't perfect either - the compiler sometimes seems to stops watching my folder, leaving me scratching my head for a few minutes over why my changes have had no effect)

Personally, I'd recommend just using the require.js coffeescript plugin for development - if it becomes too much of a performance problem then you could easily just switch to using the command line compiler in watch mode.   Converting your require calls should just be a case of a simple search & replace I'd imagine.